# No error but data is not getting deleted from Sqlite database using delete

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-delete

I am trying to delete the data from table and was able to write the command but unfortunately data is not getting deleted.. There is no error or exception reported but nothing is happening.

Checked the similar posts in stackoverflow but nothing is helping me and unable to understand where I am going wrong.

Below is my code

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.add(Calendar.MONTH, -0);
backup_date=((c.get(Calendar.DATE)-1)+"/"+(c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)+"/"+c.get(Calendar.YEAR));

System.out.println(backup_date);
                Database.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getWritableDatabase().beginTransaction();
                result=Database.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getWritableDatabase().delete(tablename, column2 + " < '" + backup_date + "'", null);
                Database.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getWritableDatabase().setTransactionSuccessful();
                if(result!=1){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Problem with deletion try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("deleted successfully");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data deleted successfully for the date " + backup_date, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: your comparison cannot work. example : `01/01/2015 < 12/10/2010`?

Comment: also `if(result!=1){` how do you know there will be exactly 1 deletion?

Comment: @njzk2 thanks for your reply... result is output of raw query.... and that is my problem...how can i make correct combination... i am out of ideas... banging my head.. can you help me

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you didn't call `endTransaction`.

Also, this probably isn't your main problem, but your logic for calculating the date won't work in December or on the first day of a month (and possibly other times too). Rather than trying to manipulate the individual date fields separately, make a new variable with the original date, then add a month and subtract a day. Then work with that date. Trying to adjust individual fields in a vacuum is never going to work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... I called it in finally clause...Do I need to write after `endtransactionsuccessful`?

Comment: It does need to be after `setTransactionSuccessful` but a finally clause ought to be OK, I think.

Comment: Excuse me,Considering your reputation I should not be telling this to you, but please avoid giving mutiple answers on the same question..Thank you.. :)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with having two answers to a question. The system allows for it. I've combined them anyway.